# UIImageView erroneously moves up in parent when clicked on

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an ImageViewController that presents an ImageZoomView (which currently doesn't zoom yet, but it will soon).  When I tap on the image, the entire image will shift upwards slightly.  This should not happen, the image should stay in it's place until a user swipes or pinches.

The ImageViewController lives inside a UIPageViewController that allows swiping between views.  However, the only issue I have is with the ImageViewController (i.e. the VideoViewController and PdfViewController both work fine and do not shift upwards on a tap)

ImageZoomView is a UIScrollView with a UIImageView as it's child control.

ImageZoomView:

```
public class ImageZoomView : UIScrollView
{
    private UIImage _image;
    private UIImageView _imageView;

    public ImageZoomView()
    {
        _imageView = new UIImageView
        {
            ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        };

        AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
        ClipsToBounds = true;
        AddSubview(_imageView);
    }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        var imageWidth = Bounds.Width;
        _imageView.Frame = new CGRect(
            Bounds.Left, Bounds.Top,
            imageWidth, imageWidth / _image.Size.Width * _image.Size.Height);

        ContentSize = _imageView.Bounds.Size;
    }

    public void DisplayImage(UIImage image)
    {
        _image = image;
        _imageView.Image = image;
    }
}
```

ImageViewController:

```
public class ImageViewController : AssetViewController
{
    private ImageZoomView _imageView;

    public ImageViewController(int index, Media media) : base(index, media) { }

    public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
        _imageView.Frame = View.Bounds;
    }

    public override void LoadView()
    {
        _imageView = new ImageZoomView()
        {
            Index = Index,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
        };
        _imageView.DisplayImage((_media as LocalMedia<UIImage>).Resource);
        View = _imageView;
    }
}
```

AssetViewController:

```
public abstract class AssetViewController : UIPageViewController
{
    protected Media _media;

    public AssetViewController(int index, Media media)
    {
        _media = media;
        Index = index;
        View.BackgroundColor = Globals.ColorDark;
    }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public Media CurrentMedia { get { return _media; } }
}
```

Comment: Do you have inside VideoViewController or PdfViewController views derived from UIScrollView?

Comment: @YuriS No, neither the VideoViewController or the PdfViewController have any dependency on the UIScrollView class.  Both classes derive from UIViewController; the PdfViewController basically uses a UIImageView to display the document (no UIScrollView parent though) and the VideoViewController uses an AVPlayer.  I do believe that the default behavior of the UIScrollView is the culprit of this problem however I have no idea what I need to do to fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately AVPlayer is not free so I canot reproduce this. Can you simplify the code to exhibit the same problem but without AVPlayer? Also the whole project source code would help to exactly reproduce what you have. If I start creating my storyboard with controllers and constraints that may not match with what you have. Any chance to get source from dropbox or github but without AVPlayer?

Comment: The problem shouldn't have anything to do with AVPlayer.  If you create a UIPageViewController that has a few ImageViewControllers in it, you should see that the first time you tap on an image, you'll see the image move up about 50 pixels or so causing what feels like to the user a glitch.  I'm almost positive it has something to do with the fact that the UIImageView is a child of a UIScrollView (which is the ImageZoomView).  It's almost like the image is initially placed in the center of the screen and then when a user taps, the image is then shifted up to the top of the screen.

Comment: Yes, but now I have override all your Media code to use UIImage, kind of time consuming :-)

Comment: Gotcha, I see what you mean now.  Here's a simple way around the Media class; replace any Media reference with a UIImage reference.  The Media class was a convenience for other parts of the application, here it isn't really necessary (other than the fact that it carries a UIImage with it).  So if you replace Media with UIImage, everything should still work.  Just replace the line _imageView.DisplayImage((_media as LocalMedia<UIImage>).Resource); with _imageView.DisplayImage(_media);  This should work because now _media is a UIImage, not a Media object.

Comment: I have a question. What are you trying to do with an image? Do you try to scale it? (You set ScaleAspectFill) Then why you need scroll view? Or you want to show it in original size? Then why you recalculate _imageView.Frame. Do you want to preserve aspect ratio?

Comment: In LayoutSubviews you set ContentSize the same as _imageView.Frame. It kills the whole idea of having scroll view.

Comment: @YuriS I am trying to fit the image into the view with respect to it's aspect ratio.  So if the image is too large to fit, it should be scaled down to fit and allow zooming.  I know there are issues with this code, I am quite new to iOS development and it seems like it's quite a bit different than .NET and WPF.  Any assistance you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128207/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-kformeck).

Answer (score 0):

Few things causing problems

1. All your controllers are derived from UIPageViewController. The content controllers should not be derived from UIPageViewController
2. In ImageViewController the code `View = _imageView;` substitutes main View of controller to ScrollView. I suggest to use `AddSubview(_imageView);`  What I saw that this erroneous movement shifts not the scroll view but somehow view of the whole controller.
3. LayoutSubviews is called pretty often and calculates the same thing all the time as neither image size nor scroll bounds are changing.

Below suggested improvements.

ImageViewController is content controller inside PageViewController and ImageZoomView is the scroll view inside ImageViewController

PageViewController

```
public partial class PageViewController : UIPageViewController
{
    public PageViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        List<ImageViewController> pages = new List<ImageViewController>();
        UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            ImageViewController ctrl = (ImageViewController)board.InstantiateViewController("imageControllerStoryboardID");
            ctrl.Index = i;
            pages.Add(ctrl);
        }
        DataSource = new PageDataSource(pages);
        View.Frame = View.Bounds;
        //Set the initial content (first page)
        SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { pages[0] }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, false, s => { });
    }


}

public class PageDataSource : UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    List<ImageViewController> pages;

    public PageDataSource(List<ImageViewController> pages)
    {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    override public UIViewController GetPreviousViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {
        var currentPage = referenceViewController as ImageViewController;
        if (currentPage.Index == 0)
        {
            return pages[pages.Count - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            return pages[currentPage.Index - 1];
        }
    }

    override public UIViewController GetNextViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {
        var currentPage = referenceViewController as ImageViewController;
        return pages[(currentPage.Index + 1) % pages.Count];
    }
}
```

ImageViewController

```
public partial class ImageViewController : UIViewController
{
    public int Index;
    private ImageZoomView _imageView;

    public ImageViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        _imageView = new ImageZoomView(UIImage.FromFile("MergedImage.png"), View.Frame)
        {
            Index = Index,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue,
        };
        View.AddSubview(_imageView);
    }

}
```

ImageZoomView

```
public class ImageZoomView : UIScrollView
{
    private UIImage _image;
    private UIImageView _imageView;

    public ImageZoomView(UIImage image, CGRect frame):base()
    {
        _imageView = new UIImageView
        {
            ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill,
        };

        _image = image;
        _imageView.Image = image;
        Frame=_imageView.Frame = frame;


        AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
        ClipsToBounds = true;
        AddSubview(_imageView);

        ContentSize = new CGSize(Frame.Width, Frame.Width / _image.Size.Width * _image.Size.Height);
        _imageView.Center = new CGPoint(ContentSize.Width / 2, ContentSize.Height / 2);
    }



    public int Index { get; set; }

}
```

There are still some code left from original sample as unused Index field and private _image variables. May be useful in the future, so I kept them around